# Comparing Cell value of gridview with textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with 6 columns
`(SAPUserID ,SAPDescription,SAPPassword,OSUserID,OSDescription,OSPassword)` and a `CHANGE PASSWORD` button. After clicking this button the panel (`pnlChangePwd`) below the grid view becomes visible containing 3 textboxes`(User ID, New Password, Confirm Password)` and a `Save` button.At present if I type new password same as old one, It accepts. How to compare the value in `txtNewPassword` with cell value of SAPPassword or OSPassword in grid view?

Note: at a time only 3 columns are visible depending upon the data user want(SAP or OS )

Code for Grid view:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvPassInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                          CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" DataKeyNames="user_id" 
                          CssClass="Gridview"  OnRowEditing="gvPassInfo_RowEditing"
                          OnRowCommand="gvPassInfo_RowCommand"  OnRowDataBound="gvPassInfo_RowDataBound">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <Columns>                                       
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSAPUserId" runat="server">
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblOSUserId" runat="server">
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSAPDescription" runat="server">
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblOSDescription" runat="server">
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSAPPassword" runat="server">
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblOSPassword" runat="server">
                            </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Change Password">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnChangePass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/PW.jpg" CausesValidation="false"
                                             CommandName="Edit" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: is there only one row in the grid

Comment: please check the question which i have edited... not sure about the rows in the grid view.

Comment: Can you include the markup for the griview on your aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the Save button

```
    var currentRow = gvPassInfo.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Single(r => ((Label)r.FindControl("lblSAPUserId")).Text == txtUserId.Text);
    bool doesMatch = ((Label)currentRow.FindControl("lblOSPassword")).Text == "NewPassword";
```

However it is better to search for password in collection which you are binding to the grid.

Comment: yes, there is image button for each row. when u click on any button the User id is copied into txtUserId field.

Comment: problem solved:) juz save executed query in one string variable and compare it with textbox value..